# Microsoft sql server. How to setup and import special chars like ø

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an csv-file with special chars used in Holland or Denmark.
I want to import the csv into an Microsoft sql server 2008. But I only get "°" instead of "ø".

I have tried Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS collation.

I have heard that it shold work with UTF-8 but I do not know how to set that in Ms-sql...
CSV file is generated from MySQL probably with UTF-8.

I import with:

BULK
INSERT 
FROM "temp..."
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

Csv file:

1;ÆgidiusB

2;Norkøping

Comment: It's not clear how you're importing the data, but MSDN [documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289(v=sql.100).aspx) how to import Unicode data using `bcp.exe` or `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the read...after looking more into the link i found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BULK INSERT needs
CODEPAGE = 'ACP'

So this worked:

BULK

INSERT doorvaartenTest

FROM "c:..."

WITH

(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',

CODEPAGE = 'ACP'

)

Also resaved files as ANSI instead of UTF-8